# Can not update database with Entity Framework Core 3.1.3

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.1

I'm using EF Core for a ASP.Net web API application and trying to create a PostgreSQL database from my model (Basic Microsoft documentation exemple)

I manage to create the migration with "**Add-Migration**" but the next step, when I do "**Update-Database**" I have this error :

```
> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
>   Failed executing DbCommand (15ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text',
>   CommandTimeout='30'] CREATE TABLE "Blogs" (
>       "BlogId" integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
>       "Url" text NULL,
>       CONSTRAINT "PK_Blogs" PRIMARY KEY ("BlogId") );
> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42601: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « GENERATED »
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So, the problem was that i wanted to use PostgreSQL 9.4, but EF Core 3 bisicly supporting only from PostgreSQL 10 and up.

The solution is to say that you are using the version 9.4 with adding an option to the context.

Exemple on Startup.cs :

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
                options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), o => o.SetPostgresVersion(9, 4)));
```

Or on the context file :

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), o => o.SetPostgresVersion(9, 4)));
        }
```